# Set the Contextual Filter: Author uid. to a default user?

Tags: views

I have a view called Map Items showing a list of map markers in a chart.

Info: I have 3 Accounts in my drupal installation called person1, person2, and admin.

I've set the contextual filter to Author uid: User ID from Logged in user. and its working perfectly, but what I want some additional setting that when there is no logged in user I could set person1's map item to show. Right now when there is no logged in user the view shows the map item of admin user and not person1.

How am I going to accomplish this?

Comment: in contextual filters instead of selecting User ID from Logged in user select php code and write some code like

Answer (score 0):

In contextual filters instead of selecting User ID from Logged in user select php code and write some code like

```
global $user;
if($user->uid > 0){
$uid = user_load($user->uid);

$roles = $uid->roles;
if(in_array('administrator', $roles)){
return 'uid of the logged in user';
//print_r($uid->roles['3']);exit;
}
else{
return FALSE;
}
}
else {
return 'return here person1 uid';
}
```

Comment: I'm new to drupal and I'm still in the process of learning stuff. So what do you mean by "return 'uid of the logged in user'; " What should I put there?

Comment: return person1 uid means that you have to return the user uid of person1 here.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: How do I return the uid of the logged user, or uid of person1? How do I get the uid for a specific user?

Comment: if the user is looged in you can get the id by using global $user; $uid = $user->uid; print $uid;

or Simply pass 

$uid = 'numeric id';